# How to verify if the radio check button is disabled in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, assertion

I want to verify if the radio buttons in the second line are disabled when I choose 'No' in the first line. Wondering what exactly I should do after clicking on 'No' ?  Like and IsDispllyed or IsEnabled?
[image: 1]

HTML when check box is enabled :

```html
<input class="bookingAttended" type="radio" name="inspection_booking_fastTrackTriage" value="Y">
```

HTML when check box is disabled :

```html
<input class="bookingAttended" type="radio" name="inspection_booking_fastTrackTriage" value="Y" disabled="">
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: There is the `element.isEnabled()` function in the java bindings which looks for the `disabled` attribute on the element.  Without more context I'm not sure if that will accompilsh what you want. Can you please post the code you are running, and describe exactly what you want to accomplish that you haven't yet?

Comment: boolean elementIsEnabled=  driver.findElement(bookingAttendedYes).isEnabled();
      return elementIsEnabled;

Comment: And in my step definition, I am doing my assertions :         Assert.assertFalse(repxPage.fastTrackTriagebuttonsShouldBeDisabled());

Comment: I can see the checkbox is disabled but IsEnabled is always returning true,which is failing my assertion.

Comment: When you see the checkbox is disabled, are you talking about just how it looks in the UI? Can you look and see how exactly the element changes between the enabled and disabled states?

Also, please post your code in the question instead of the comments. :)

Comment: Yes, disabled just on the UI. Apologies,have posted the HTML now in the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see in the `HTML` of the input element you provided, it has `disabled` attribute when it is disabled and missing that attribute when the button is enabled.
So, you can use

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='inspection_booking_fastTrackTriage'] and @disabled"))
```

and validate that the returned list is not empty or wait until that element is present with the following code

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='inspection_booking_fastTrackTriage'] and @disabled")));
```

I guess the `xpath` above is unique. Otherwise you will have to use some relations to some additional parent element to uniquely locate that element.